# Importing external js files and using them in React. Method not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The design team of my project has provided me a js file generated with CoffeeSript that merges several libraries in one file (those being [Fancy Select](https://github.com/paulstraw/FancySelect), [modulejs](https://larsjung.de/modulejs/), [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) and [wNumb](https://refreshless.com/wnumb/)).

What I did so far is adding a `script` tag in my `index.html` where my `<div id="react-root"></div>` lives to import the file. AFAIK, the methods inside the file should be available as global variables. There is also an import of jQuery 3.

I can tell that the library is being loaded because the Fancy Select is transforming my normal select boxes to fancy ones, but now, in a React Component I try to call Fancy Select's `.fancySelect()` method but the runtime console is telling me that the method doesn't exist.

```
Uncaught TypeError: theSelectBox.fancySelect is not a function
    at Day.componentDidUpdate (EcoTariFechaNacimientoView.js:34)
```

Here's the problematic snippet of code:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    let theSelectBox = $(this.refs.selectDay);
    console.log(theSelectBox.val()); //<-- Works fine.
    theSelectBox.fancySelect(); //<-- This doesn't.
}
```

While I can get the data I want with the line that works, **why .fancySelect() doesn't work?** I'm calling it exactly as the documentation states, passing a jQuery selector pointing to the select. I also followed [this guide](http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/), which helped quite a lot.

**I'm lucky I ended not needing it, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong in case I need it in the future.**

I want to point out that I can't modify the js lib myself, as the React app is being embedded in another website where I don't have control on the available libs.

---

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="tariff">
        <div id="react-root" class="tariff__content"></div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="javascripts/site.js"></script>     
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**EcoTariFechaNacimientoView.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import $ from "jquery";
var request = require('superagent');

const URL_ECO = require('../constants/config/UrlsEnvironment').CURRENT_URL_ECO;
const URI_ECO_VFLX_SERVLET = require('../constants/config/UrlsEnvironment').URI_ECO_VFLX_SERVLET;

class Day extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let days = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
            days.push(i);
        }

        this.dayList = days.map(day => {
            let val = (day < 10) ? ("0" + day) : day;
            return <option key={val.toString()} value={val}>{val}</option>;
        });

        this.handleDayChange = this.handleDayChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleDayChange(event) {
        this.props.onDayChange(event.target.value);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        let theSelectBox = $(this.refs.selectDay);
        console.log(theSelectBox.val()); //<-- Works fine.
        theSelectBox.fancySelect(); //<-- This doesn't.
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select required
                    name="select_day"
                    ref="selectDay"
                    id="select_day"
                    className="eco-select"
                    value={this.props.day}
                    onChange={this.handleDayChange}
                    onBlur={this.props.onBlur}
            >
                <option key="" value="">DD</option>
                {this.dayList}
            </select>
        );
    }
}

class Month extends React.Component {...}

class Year extends React.Component {...}

class PrivateEcoTariFechaNacimientoView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let date = this.props.initValue.split('-');

        let yearValue = date[0];
        let monthValue = date[1];
        let dayValue = date[2];

        this.state = {
            day : dayValue,
            month : monthValue,
            year : yearValue,
            validity : false,
            validText :'',
        };

        this.handleYearChange = this.handleYearChange.bind(this);
        this.handleMonthChange = this.handleMonthChange.bind(this);
        this.handleDayChange = this.handleDayChange.bind(this);

        this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
    }

    handleYearChange(year) {
        this.setState({
            year: year
        });
    }

    handleMonthChange(month) {
        this.setState({
            month: month
        });
    }

    handleDayChange(day) {
        this.setState({
            day: day
        });
    }

    updateCSS(result) {
        var css = 'error';
        var valid = false;

        if (result) {
            css = 'valid';
            valid = true;
        }   

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            validText: css,
            validity : valid
        }))
    }

    handleBlur() {
        this.validator( ()=>{this.updateCSS(true)},
                        ()=>{this.updateCSS(false)}
        );
    }

    validator = (funOk = () =>{} , funKo = () =>{}) => {
        let year = this.state.year;     
        let month = this.state.month;
        let day = this.state.day;

        if (day && month && year) {
            let URL = URL_ECO + URI_ECO_VFLX_SERVLET;
            let fecha = this.state.year + '-' + this.state.month + '-' + this.state.day;

            // Async call    
            request.post(URL)
            .send('process=validFecha')
            .send('data=' + fecha)
            .end(function(err, res){
                if (err || !res.ok) {
                    funKo();
                    console.log('Oh no! error');
                } else {
                    console.log('yay got ' + JSON.stringify(res.body));
                    if (res.body) {
                        funOk();
                    } else {
                        funKo();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            funKo();
        }
    }

    okContinue = () => {
        this.props.updateState(this.state.year + '-' + this.state.month + '-' + this.state.day);    
        this.props.history.push(this.props.next);
    }

    submitStep = (event) => {
        if (this.state.validity) {          
            this.validator(
                () => { 
                    this.updateCSS(true);
                    this.okContinue();  
                },
                () => {
                    this.updateCSS(false)
                }
            );
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateCSS(true);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="tariff-form">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="tariff-form__inner">
                            <form id="form_fecha_nacimiento">
                                <label className="tariff-form__label">Selecciona o escribe tu fecha de nacimiento</label>
                                <div className="tariff-form__field">
                                    <div className="form-date">
                                        <div className="form-select js-select">
                                            <Day    day={this.state.day}
                                                    onDayChange={this.handleDayChange}
                                                    onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                                                    className={this.state.validText}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-select js-select">
                                            <Month  month={this.state.month}
                                                    onMonthChange={this.handleMonthChange}
                                                    onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                                                    className={this.state.validText}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-select js-select">
                                            <Year   year={this.state.year}
                                                    onYearChange={this.handleYearChange}
                                                    onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                                                    className={this.state.validText}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <a id="next_button" className="button button--xl button--full" tabIndex="0" onMouseUp={this.submitStep}>Comienza a calcular</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const EcoTariFechaNacimientoView = withRouter(PrivateEcoTariFechaNacimientoView);
module.exports = EcoTariFechaNacimientoView;
```

Comment: I doubt how you can call `.fancySelect` on the DOM reference. You need to log it to the console and check the documentation of the third-party library